# Area of a convex pentagon

Tags: geometry

Let ABCDE be a convex pentagon. $AB = AE = CD = 1. $$\angle AED = \angle ABC = 90^{\circ}$. DE + BC = 1.

I have very easily shown that area of triangles AED and ABC sum to half into 1/2. But it seems that I am only able to get there. To find the area of triangle ADC I have tried to take its sides in terms of ED but that seems to be too complex. I am stuck.

Comment: Check your question because  as written you say both $CD=1$ and $DE+DC=1$ which implies $DE=0$

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it DE + BC = 1. Sorry for the late response, my internet connection is painfully slow.

Comment: I would suggest continuing $BC$ and $DE$ until they meet at $F$ and considering the resulting quadrilateral $ABFE$ which is cyclic. There are several similar triangles. I seem to get an answer which depends on the base angle, but I haven't checked the detail.

Comment: Mark Bennet, I would like to ask you from where do you get such bursts of intuition, for I don't think I would have been able to start with such constructions. This is a point, for which I have been really seeking an answer. I am not able to think like that, which is very important for olympiad questions. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area comes out to be one unit..

Extend sides BC and ED to meet at point P..

Let $\angle APB = \alpha$

=>  $\angle APE = \alpha$

$AB = AE = CD = 1$

=> $BP = EP = \cot{\alpha}$

and $P_{ABPE} = 2\cdot P_{ABP} = \cot{\alpha}$

In $\triangle PDC$,

$ \angle{DPC} = 2 \cdot \alpha $

$CD=1$

$PD + PC = (\cot(\alpha)-DE) + (\cot(\alpha)-CB) = 2 \cdot \cot(\alpha) - 1$

Also, Using cosine rule,

$\overline{CD}^2 = \overline{PD}^2 + \overline{PC}^2 - 2 \cdot \overline{PD} \cdot \overline{PC} \cdot \cos{2\alpha}
= (PD + PC)^2 - 2 \cdot PD \cdot PC \cdot (1 + \cos{2\alpha})$

Hence, $PD \cdot PC = \frac{(2\cot{\alpha} - 1)^2 - 1}{2(1 + \cos{2\alpha})}$

Now , $P_{PDC} = PD \cdot PC \cdot \frac{\sin{2\alpha}}{2}$.

which on simplification gives

Area $P_{PDC} = \cot(\alpha) - 1$

Therefore, $P_{ABCDE} = \cot(\alpha) - P_{PDC} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let me scale things up to $AB=AE=CD=BC+DE=2$, so that what needs proving is that the triangle ACD has area $2$.  Now let $BC=1+x$ and $DE=1-x$ for some $x$, so that ACD has sides of length $a=\sqrt{5+2x+x^2}$, $b=\sqrt{5-2x+x^2}$, and $c=2$, with semi-perimeter $s=(a+b+c)/2$.  By Heron's formula, its area is $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, so what we really need to show is that

$$(a+b+2)(a+b-2)(2+(a-b))(2-(a-b))=64$$

Grinding through the algebra, we see

$$\begin{align}
(a+b+2)(a+b-2)(2+(a-b))(2-(a-b))&=((a+b)^2-4)(4-(a-b)^2)\cr
&=4((a+b)^2+(a-b)^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2-16\cr
&=8(a^2+b^2)-(a^2-b^2)^2-16\cr
&=8(10+2x^2)-(4x)^2-16\cr
&=64
\end{align}$$

which is all we need.

Answer (score 1):

Area is 1 for the following very simple reason. This convex pentagon *DOES NOT EXIST* — as a pentagon, that is. It is a square. If you extend and intersect lines $BC$ and $DE$ to obtain point F, then $ABFE$ is a square with unit side

[image: "Pentagon" ABCDE]

However, since $1 = CD^2 = CF^2 + FD^2 = x^2 + (1-x)^2 = 1 - 2x + 2x^2$, we have that $x = x^2$ and thus, $x=0$ or $x = 1$, meaning that point $C$ coincides with $B$ or $F$ (and $D$ — with $F$ or $E$ respectively).

So area is 1 but the polygon itself is not a "real" pentagon. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

rotate $\triangle ADE $  with point A fixed, while AB meets to AE. let the rotated triangle, $\triangle AE'D'$ .Then E',B',C is on one line. (because $\angle DEA + \angle ABC =90^\circ$ )
Then D'C=1.
Then D'C=CD=1, CA=CA, DA=D'A.
thus $\triangle D'CA \equiv \triangle DCA(sss)$ .
Thus the area of two triangles are same. And the area of $\triangle D'CA $ = $ \frac {1}{2} $. Thus, the area of pentagon is two times of that. Thus, the answer is 1.